# Android: zxing open browser instead return to app

Tags: android-intent, barcode, zxing, onactivityresult

i have a zxing barcode reader integrated in my app, and it work (or at least, it was working).
Now, after the scan, it open the browser by itself instead of return to the app!
If i go to the app by task manager, the onActivityResut has worked.
So the problem is: it open the browser and don't return to the app taking it to foreground.
It was working, i don't know why now is broken... maybe android 4?
my code (which is very normal):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE","QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent,0);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0 && isOnline()) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            // CODE
        }else if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){
            // CODE
        }
    }else{
        // CODE
    }
}
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: It's not quite clear what this means. Are you invoking a web page to scan? It's just responding to your Intent, so you may have set up your browser accidentally to handle the reply Intent?

Comment: no no, i haven't touch the code. it's an issue with android 4 i think.
i call the intent written in my post.
it have always worked like this:
- the user click scan
- the scanner appear
- after the scan it return to the app and invoke onActivityResult

now it work like this:
- the user click scan
- the scanner appear
- after the scan, the app do the onActivityResult but remain in background and the default browser appear pointing to the scanned url